# Editar ultimo elemnto de un array php foreach

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

```
<?php


$resp = $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "var fechas = {";

foreach($resp as $i){   
    echo "'".$i['fecha']."' : '".$i['visita']." @  ". $i['casa']."',";
}

echo "};";
```

y esto muestra lo siguiente:

```
var fechas = {
 '2019-03-10' : 'Equipo A @  Equipo D',
 '2019-03-11' : 'Equipo B @  Equipo D',
 '2019-03-12' : 'Equipo C @  Equipo D',
};
```

Y lo que quiero es que en el ultimo elemento no salga la coma(,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de volcar directamente la salida desde el bucle con echo, coloca el contenido en una cadena y luego elimina la última letra que será la coma:

```
<?php
    $resp = $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "var fechas = {";
    $salida = "";
    foreach($resp as $i){   
        $salida .= "'".$i['fecha']."' : '".$i['visita']." @  ". $i['casa']."',";
    }
    echo substr($salida, 0, -1);
    echo "};";
```

También puedes usar trim de la siguiente manera:

```
    echo trim($salida, ',');
```

Comment: me da el siguiente error que es la linea dentro del foreach                    <b>Warning</b>:  A non-numeric value encountered in

Comment: Cierto, en lugar de += es .= pues se trata de concatenar cadenas, lo escribí directamente aquí y me equivoqué. Ya lo he arreglado.

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias!

Comment: Funciona con los dos, puedes probar online en http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c04fc43c1b6e6f145cd9f6efa347da5e4e2c0d8f eso es así porque trim funciona para el/los carácteres al principio y al final, si hay una coma al inicio y solo quieres eliminar la del final, entonces si, rtrim

Comment: @track3r probe y busque una explicación para el trim en vez del rtrim, como no existe una coma al inicio funciona la función trim (elimina un carácter del inicio y del final), por ende si utiliza rtrim (para eliminar solo un carácter al final) igual funciona.

Comment: Si, edité el comentario para aclarar pero ya lo dijiste tu :)